# How to remove duplicates in a list of lists, keeping the element with the highest value based on the second element in the list? Python

Tags: python

I have a list of lists with repeating items in the first entry of the list. I would like to remove duplicates and only keep the items with the highest score (based on the second entry of the list)

```
list_dup = [["Apple", 24],
["Apple", 23], 
["Sun", 15], 
["Apple", 2], 
["Sun", 1],
["Blue", 15]
]
```

Output:

```
list_dup = [["Apple", 24], 
    ["Sun", 15], 
    ["Blue", 15]
    ]
```

Comment: Only values >/= 0?

Comment: That is a good point @wwii. the List does not contain negative values, but it could contain some in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(list_dup).groupby(0).max().reset_index().values.tolist()
```

Step by step:

- convert the list in a `pd.DataFrame`;
- group rows according the value of the first column (column `0`, the one containing the strings);
- taking the max values for the other columns for each group (in your case you have just one other column, the one containing the integers);
- convert the resulting `pd.DataFrame` in a numpy `array` (with `.values`) and then  converting it in a `list`.

Comment: I feel like pandas is using a 5-pound sledgehammer to drive a tack nail.

Comment: @James I feel it too, but I love sledgehammers and I don't know how big is the dataset. Cycling on groups could probably require more time for a big dataset.

Comment: How about a single pass over the list constructing a dictionary- like [Francesco Pinna's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74717873/2823755),?

Comment: @wwii It works, In this case I think the best solution is the most performing one, and it only depends on the data. I've assumed the dataset is a bigger one and so I avoided the loops, but probably I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If the order of the output list is not important, you can use `sorted` to sort the list by the first elements of the sub-lists, then use `itertools.groupby` to pull the pull together groups based on the first elements, and finally use `max` to get the highest element based on the second element.

```
from itertools import groupby

[max(g, key=lambda x: x[1]) for _, g in groupby(sorted(list_dup), key=lambda x: x[0])]
# returns:
[['Apple', 24], ['Blue', 15], ['Sun', 15]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Many possibilities. One of the clearest may be:

```
m_d = {}
for k in list_dup:
    if k[0] in m_d:
        if m_d[k[0]] < k[1]:
            m_d[k[0]] = k[1]
    else:
        m_d[k[0]] = k[1]

list_no_dup = [[k, v] for k, v in m_d.items()]
```